# Autorotation in ios 5 vs. ios 6 issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

I have an iPad app that must support iOS 5.0 and later.  I have a bug that behaves differently in 5.0/5.1 than it does in 6.0.  The issue is a view controller in a tabbarcontroller that pushes a modal view, which in turn pushes a full-screen view via navigationController.  The problem is, when in the full-screen view, if the iPad is rotated, the underlying viewcontroller (one in the tabbarcontroller) doesn't rotate.  Now let me break down the differences in iOS versions:

First of all, this viewController in question implements shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation (returns YES) as well as willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation.

In iOS 6.0, I noticed that the rotation methods (willRotate... & willAnimate...) were not being called, so I registered it to receive the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notification and execute the code from the two Rotate methods if I received that notification and the other methods hadn't executed.  That fixed the issue in iOS 6.0.

Problem is, in 5.0/5.1 the rotation methods (willRotate... & willAnimate...) ARE being executed, but the view is not rotating.  If the "full-screen view" is not presented over top of this view controller and the iPad is rotated, these two methods execute and the views rotate accordingly.

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Things I've tried other than that stated above.

I've tried checking the UIDeviceOrientation and converting it to a UIInterfaceOrientation and calling [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:xxx];  The view still displays wrong.

Comment: For starters, the API to support orientations has changed in iOS, so you may want to experiment with supporting both the new and old method.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Comment: I've read the iOS 6.0 release notes and have not implemented that method simply because my issue is with 5.0/5.1  The bug is fixed for iOS 6.0 (although I may implement the new methods for good measure).

Answer (score 0):

When the two rotation methods are being executed, do the CAAffineTransformation for your view. when you are back to normal, again do the same with -90 degree.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html